# Reference Excel Range inside SQL Query Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I would like SQL inside of my excel workbook to reference a variable range of cells that's also within the workbook. This will save me time from having to constantly go back and forth between EXCEL and SQL (all in one place). The variable cells that I would like to reference are in column B on Sheet 1. The range will always start in B3 but end anywhere between B4 and B3000. The values in those cells are variable as well. This is the SQL query that I have thus far but I am getting the attached alert:

```
DECLARE @issr AS TEXT
SET @issr = [Sheet1!$B$3:B3000]

select VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4 from T_POF_IN_FLG_CRM_V2
where VALUE1 in @issr
```

I am successfully connected to the correct Database and Server but there's something wrong with the query.. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have been working on this for a week and even the SQL 'PROS' at my firm do not know how to reference excel cells using an SQL query that's stored inside of the excel workbook.

[image: sql]

Comment: That syntax looks unusual. What happens if you try `select * from [Sheet1!$B$3:B3000]`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you not need () around the @issr variable?  For example, where VALUE1 in (@issr)